# update configmap values which are in yaml format

Tags: python, shell, kubernetes, yaml, configmap

below is the configmap yaml i need to update "mnc-0878787889" ,"mncidn-090876900" , start-date: 2019-06-27T10:00:00 values to "mnc-099999999" ,"mncidn-06666666" , start-date: 2010-06-27T10:00:00 i tried using oc patch couldnot able to update so i need parse yaml and need to update and i cannot use yq is there any other way i can achive this using shell script or python script

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  data-provisioning.yaml: |-
    # Copyright (c) 2019-2020 .
    # All Rights Reserved.
    #
    # This software is proprietary information of
    # Development NP.

    datatype-provisioning:
      - company-id:
          - "mnc-0878787889"
          - "mncidn-090876900"
        available-service:
          - "first-package"
        start-date: 2019-06-27T10:00:00
        end-date: 2050-06-27T10:30:00
        propagate-value: true
        info-level: "MEDIUM"
kind: ConfigMap
```

Comment: any way we can do using oc patch and update configmap yaml file lot of resources say oc patch works but in real time oc patch not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use envsubst. create template yaml like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  data-provisioning.yaml: |-
    # Copyright (c) 2019-2020 .
    # All Rights Reserved.
    #
    # This software is proprietary information of
    # Development NP.

    datatype-provisioning:
      - company-id:
          - "mnc-0878787889"
          - "mncidn-090876900"
        available-service:
          - "first-package"
        start-date: ${START_DATE}
        end-date: ${END_DATE}
        propagate-value: true
        info-level: "MEDIUM"
kind: ConfigMap
```

Go to shell and export START_DATE and END_DATE with required values
And now run command:

```
cat <yaml_file_name> | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -
```